# PHP: Insert a substring into a HTML string after every N characters?

Tags: php, html, newline

I have a long string that will be displayed on my page. I want it to have a line break after every 40 chars. How can I insert these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `<br>` or `<wbr>` tag:

```
wordwrap($string, 40, "<wbr>", true);
```

Basically, `<wbr>` represents a place where the browser is allowed to break the word on a new line, but it won't display a space if it doesn't have to.

`<br>` on the other hand will *always* create a line break.

Comment: So if OP wants to insert resulting string to database, or send via cURL he will send with that unwanted `<wbr>`?

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov If he wants to insert/send *that* particular string: Of course. But he can also choose not to if it isn't what he wants ;) I usually format when outputting and store the raw materials in the database.

Comment: @asprin Yeah, that would be XHTML if that's what you're using.

Comment: @phant0m so isn't it better then to post solution which do *exactly* what OP wants? if he wants newline he should use `"\n"` and nothing else, right? if he wants line break on HTML page - `<br />`

Comment: @phant0m You've mistaken me as the OP. I'm simply testing the code because it's new to me and wanted to see if it works

Comment: @Alexander You are right of course, but the question is: Which kind of newline did he mean?

Comment: The OP just indicated what he wanted

Answer (score 3):

use chunk_split [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

```
chunk_split($string, 40, "\n");
```

Comment: <?php
    $str="qwertyuiop";
    $str = chunk_split($str, 4, "\n");
    echo $str;
    ?>

Comment: @asprin If you think this is inserting a space (it isn't) try `chunk_split($string, 40, "<br />\n");` instead. HTML rendering engines don't show new-lines as line breaks, they show all whitespace collapsed as a single space.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string';
echo wordwrap($string, 40, "\n", true);
```

Comment: I've tested it before making a comment mate

Comment: If you copy pasted than you should get correct result with newlines.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov He is talking about HTML, where a newline acts as a space.

Comment: @phant0m I have no idea about what he's talking. He just *thought* its not working while the code does exactly what OP's want.

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov No, your code does not what he wants. He wants a line break on the *page*, not in the HTML source code.

Comment: @phant0m where did you find that? OP wants *insert a newline after each 40 chars*

Comment: I guessed from his first comment `Doesn't work. Puts a space after 40th character` and he confirms it: `Shoot, you're right @phant0m it was HTML`

Comment: @phant0m Who confirms it? OP?

Comment: oh... my mistake, I just assumed because he was so eagerly commenting.